# Mella Roos Disclosure Requirements (California)

Tags: taxes, california, home-ownership

I live in Washington State and I’m in the process of helping my mom purchase a home (I’m paying, but she will be living in it).

Given the competitive market, we recently put in a non-contingent offer on a very new home (2018 or 2019), that was accepted.

The next day, before we made our earnest money deposit, I stumbled across a website for the community (where the home was located) that said it had “mella roos” or special taxes.

In this case, the costs would have been an additional ~3,000 per year.

We contacted our realtor and let them know we wanted to withdraw our offer, believing this was something the seller would have known about and did not disclose.

From researching online, it does seem like this was adequate grounds for withdrawing our offer (seller knew about something that could materially affect the price of the house, there are mella roos disclosure requirements, etc.) and we should not be liable for the earnest money.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sounds more like a question for http://law.stackexchange.com, but I could argue that the presence of a "special tax" does not affect the _price_ of the home. It might impact your ability to _afford_ the home, but not the _price_.

Comment: @D Stanley, apologies if my language was “loose”.  If the seller is aware of an issue that could affect the price or value of a home.  For example, if the seller goes “oh by the way, there is a roof leak and a crack in the foundation” after a non-contingent offer has been signed; it’s my understanding that could be grounds for withdrawal.  In this case, the seller would have been paying the mella roos fees for multiple years and there is a mella roos disclosure requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be in the right.

> California Civil Code Section 1102.6b. requires that a seller whose
> home is subject to a Mello-Roos assessment must make a good faith
> effort to obtain and pass on to the buyer what is known as a Notice of
> Special Tax ...

https://realtytimes.com/consumeradvice/buyersadvice/item/27444-20140205-mello-roos-disclosures-are-often-inadequate